# Strategy advice for this regex (matching in the middle of lookahead and a lookbehind)

Tags: regex

I am using positive lookbehind and lookahead to match a word between certain parts (FROM and TO strings).

```
.*(?<=FROM)\s+(.*?)\s+(?=TO).*
```

*EDIT: That approach cannot be changed. Need to assume, not a workaround for the approach itself, thank you! It's more a theoretical question about how to deal with that lokaheads in-between matching.*

I'd like to input an string like

```
FROM table a, table2 b TO
```

and obtain as `\1` table and table2. a and b labels are optional.

My problem is that if I place something like `(?:(\w+)\s*,?)+?` for matching every table part, it seems like it's done backwards

http://regex101.com/r/mV4rD8

Comment: "a and b labels are optional" So it's optional whether they're in the input, if they're there, you don't want them in the output?

Comment: "and obtain as \1 table and table2" And you could explain what exactly you want here, in terms of capture groups? Do you want `table1` in one capture group and `table2` in another, or something else?

Comment: yes, it is optional whether they're in the input (look samples in regex101 link). I'd like to capture the same group multiple times if present, as table, table2, table3. I use (?: ()  )+? but it does not work as expected

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you don't need lookahead/behind. You can do:

```
FROM (?:(\w+)(?: \w)*(?:,)? )+TO
```

Of the three parts inside the outermost parentheses, the second and third need to be treated separately because they are optional for different reasons. The second is present if the `a` and `b` labels are present. The third is present if the table is not the last one in the list.

This will capture the table names as you described. So e.g.:

```
FROM table1 a, table2, table3 c TO
```

Will capture "table1", "table2" and "table3".

I used literal spaces, but you can replace them with `\s` if you prefer.

**EDIT:** With the lookahead and lookbehind still present, as per your requirement:

```
.*(?<=FROM)\s+(?:(\w+)(?:\s+\w)*(?:\s*,)?\s+)+(?=TO).*
```

Comment: This is giving different results in Expresso to the link you've posted. Not sure why, there's nothing in here I know of that the regex flavour should be relevant for.

Comment: I need to use lookahead and lookbehind, as this is a simplification of a more complex query, if not I could have come with a similar query, sorry. I tried yours before analyzing it but it does not work. I should have stated that assume the original approach cannot be changed

Comment: Thank you very much Ben! It's not working for me, am I missing something? http://regex101.com/r/eS4hS3

Comment: @user1352530 Updated the last version slightly to handle the whitespace as you need. That tool seems to only output the last capture for a capture group, rather than all of them for some reason